# View Will Appear does not fire on Exit Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

iOS app: My main view is PlayView. I load it in beginning. Then secondary views are segued to and when I am done with them I perform an exit segue to go back to PlayView.

Everytime ViewWillAppear fires on a view I load AdMob banner to that view. When ViewDidDisappear fires, I remove the ad banner from that view.

PlayView, however only fires ViewWillAppear initially and not when exit segue is performed. Hence I cant show nad remove ad banner on PlayView like the rest of views.

Any suggestions how to work around this problem?

Comment: You can try `viewDidAppear`, Also you can try to implement your own delegate that will trigger "ShowAdMob" when you are calling the exit segue

Comment: First of all, views are not view controllers and view controllers aren't views. Second, the `viewWillAppear` is supposed to be called when the view controller appears, at least when it is shown using standard classes, so add your code and let's see what actually is happening.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be called.  You could also place the code in prepareForSegue in one of the other view controllers, or in the unwind method in the PlayView controller.